# Can't seem to install simplegui?

Tags: installation, python-3.4

I'm using Python version 3.4.3, and I'm trying to install simplegui for my own use. However I can't do so. Python keeps giving me a syntax error.

Like so:

```
>>> python setup.py install
>>> pip -m install simplegui
```

Both return syntax errors. What's wrong?

Thanks a whole ton to whoever can help!

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command prompt not python shell.
Open cmd browse to your setup.py file and type the code :

```
    setup.py instal
```

Worked well for me (python 2.7) and should definitely work for you!
Cheers! (welcome if it works for you).

------- @ Charles Windle said :  Thanks a load @AV 198, but it still doesn't work for me. As you can see: setup.py install File "", line 1 setup.py install  SyntaxError: invalid syntax –  --------------

### Follow the Steps Exactly :

- Click on Start (Select all programs if available)
- Click on Accessories
- Click and open command prompt which is available in the accessories folder(The command prompt window opens)
- Type in the command prompt **(The window which is opened is called cmd or command prompt. Do not open python shell/script. It is different from cmd !)**

  ```
  cd..
  ```

  until the screen shows

  ```
  C:\>
  ```
- Now if suppose the address to you simplegui setup file is :

  ```
  C:\User\Username\Downloads\Simplegui\setup.py
  ```

  Type The following and press enter after typing each line :

  ```
  cd User
  cd Username
  cd Downloads
  cd Simplegui
  ```
- Now you are in your setup folder (the folder where setup.py is located).
  *The address to your setup.py file may differ in your computer. So Follow the above example and come to the folder where setup.py is located actually in your computer.*
- Now type

  ```
  dir
  ```

  You will see a list of files contained in your setup folder. See if there is setup.py available in the list which is showing. If yes continue further. If no you Must have committed some mistake and/or are in the wrong folder and Repeat the whole process from Step 4
- Now as you are in your setup folder Type the following :

  ```
  setup.py install
  ```

  The installation should start. If Still it does not start and raises an exception comment me the error message you get.

Hope That works!

Cheers Again!

Comment: well there is a spelling mistake Take it as - setup.py install

Comment: Thanks a load @AV 198, but it still doesn't work for me. As you can see:

`setup.py install`
`File "<stdin>", line 1`
`setup.py install`
` `
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I think you did not get my answer. The error message you gave me will occur only when you try to type the command in python script/shell. Read my eddited answer and follow commands exactly as it says